# Magento - remove one quantity from cart

Tags: magento, cart

I am trying to remove just one qty from my cart rather than all, but to no avail.

Can anybody help?

Here is the code I have got so far...

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app("default");
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

$yourProId = $_POST['prodID'];
$qty = 1;

foreach (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
    if ($yourProId == $item->getProductId()) {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem($item->getId())->save();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: Here is the code that works, thanks to R.S. for this!

```
$yourProId = $_POST['prodID']; 
$qty=1; 

$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
if ($item->getProduct()->getId() == $yourProId) {
    $qty = $item->getQty() - 1; // check if greater then 0 or set it to what you want
    if($qty == 0) {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem($item->getId());    
    } else {
            $item->setQty($qty);
        }
        $cartHelper->getCart()->save();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item->getProduct()->getId() == $yourProId) {
        if( $item->getQty() == 1 ){
            $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($item->getItemId())->save();
        }
        else if($item->getQty() > 1){
            $item->setQty($item->getQty() - 1)
            $cartHelper->getCart()->save();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Take a look @ /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php

See http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/30113/

Comment: I have tried this, unfortunately it didn't work. For some reason $item->getId() isn't the same as my $yourProId. When I use $item->getProductId() is returns the correct ID.

Comment: Still no luck :( It removes the product from the cart, but I don't want it to remove all the qty's. E.g. I've got 5 of the same product in the cart, when this function is ran I have 0 in the cart, but I need it to go down to 4.

Comment: Almost there now! :) One more slight problem; Let's say I have 3 in my cart, I can remove 2 but when I get down to 1 more left it doesn't remove it.

Comment: my code above is not correct.... because i'm calling removeItem... but you should use a if statement to check the qty and do a remove if 1 else subtract 1

Answer (score 0):

You can alter or remove qty using $quoteItem->setData('qty', $avl_qty);
Please refer to code for more help.

```
$quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
$avl_qty = 1;
if ($avl_qty == '0') {
  $quoteItem->getQuote()->removeItem($quoteItem->getItemId());
  throw new LocalizedException(__("This product is currently out of stock."));                    
} 
elseif ($order_qty > $avl_qty) {                   
  $quoteItem->setData('qty', $avl_qty);
  $this->_cart->save();
  $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage('Sorry we have only '.$avl_qty.' qty of this product available');                    
} 
else {                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2
you can utilize
https://yourdomain.com/rest/V1/carts/mine/items
API with Auth token and Body

```
{
   "cartItem": {
       "item_id": 49388,//item_id not SKU
       "qty": 1,        //This will overwrite quantity
       "quote_id": {{QuoteId}}
   }
}
```