# Magento: Delete item from cart

Tags: magento

I need to delete one item from cart.

I use the checkout_cart_add_product_complete event wich is fired after the cart was saved.

Then I use:

```
 $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
 $allQuoteItems = $quote->getAllItems();
    foreach ($allQuoteItems as $_item) {
        $_product = $_item->getProduct();
      if ($_product->getIsPreparedToDelete()) {
          $quote->removeItem($_item->getId());
       } 
    }        
    $quote->save();
```

But the item is still there...

I have no idea which event I can use - or if it is really possible to delte an item in the cart (I also added items, that works - with the same event..).

Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately not... I am not searching for an event, which is fired when a product is deleted... I am looking for an event, which I can use, to delete an product when a product was added to cart and save another one instead of this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ [Magento - remove one quantity from cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397952/magento-remove-one-quantity-from-cart)

```
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');

$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
   ...
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem($item->getId());
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried this - but it also doesn't work... Also tried "setCartWasUpdated(true)"...

Comment: What version of magento are you using and is your observer been executed

Comment: 1.8. And the observer works - I add products to cart within the same.

Comment: Did you take a look @ /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php to see how they do it

Answer (score 0):

Found it out.

removeItem() works outside this event, when all is saved. Within works this ($_item->isDeleted(true)):

$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

```
    $allQuoteItems = $quote->getAllItems();
    foreach ($allQuoteItems as $_item) {
        $_product = $_item->getProduct();
        f ($_product->getIsPreparedToDelete()) {
            $_item->isDeleted(true);
        } else {
            // ....
        }
    }
    $quote->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use one of the below event to observe and can use to remove particular item from cart:

sales_quote_item_save_before: When the item will be added to cart, this event will be called before the save event of that item fired.

sales_quote_save_after: And every time the whole cart will be saved this event will be fired after that.

And for your information, sales quote object is being used for handling cart.

And below is the link to the list of magento's events:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/events

Please feel free to revert back with any queries.

Regards,
Milan